# How to build JSON programmatically in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to create a JSON programmatically for `POST` method without hardcoding the key name as it can be anything.

At the moment I'm hardcoding the JSON which is fine for testing at least I know my `POST` method is working correctly.

For testing this is my current JSON looks like but it can have multiple levels.

```
var jsonFormObj = {
        'Name': value,
        'Number': value,
        'Url': value,
        'Children': [
            {
                'ChildName': value,
                'ChildNumber': value
            }
        ]
    }
```

With multi-level obj

```
var jsonFormObj = {
        'Name': value,
        'Number': value,
        'Url': value,
        'Children':{
            'ChildName': value,
            'ChildNumber': value,
            'Addresses' : [{
                    'Line 1': value,
                    'Line 2': value..
                }]
        }
    }
```

Textarea `ngFor` HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount" class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" id="{{inputSearch.name}}" rows="2" [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.value" [class.hidden]="checkedUsers.indexOf(inputSearch.name) >= 0"></textarea>
</div>
```

I tried this approach however it created a flat JSON than nested like the example above.

```
let jsonData = {}; let jsonFormObj;

     this.searchBoxCount.forEach((inputSearch: any) => {
        if (inputSearch.value != null && (inputSearch.value != "")) {
            let inputValues: any = inputSearch.value;
            var dataNameElement = inputSearch.name;
            jsonData[dataNameElement] = inputSearch.value; 
        }
    });

    jsonFormObj.push(jsonData);
```

Rendering textarea:

```
var searchParams = [];
for (var key in prop) {
  if (prop.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if (prop[key].type && prop[key].type != 'array') {
        console.log("Normal FIELD.. "+ key);
        var object = {name: key};
        searchParams.push(object);
    } else if (prop[key].type && prop[key].type === 'array') {
        console.log("ARRAY HERE TO SHOW 'ADD' BUTTON.. "+ key);
        this.arrObj = true;
    }else if (!prop[key].type) {
      console.log("NOT FIELD, BUT OBJECT.. "+ key);
      let objKeyProp = apiDefinition[prop[key].$ref.split('/')[2]].properties
      for(var obj in objKeyProp){
         if(objKeyProp.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
             object = {name: obj};
              searchParams.push(object);
          }
       }
    }                                   
  }
}
this.searchBoxCount = searchParams;
```

Result of above:

[image]

How can I create this kind of JSON programmatically? as hardcoding is not an opinion at all because objs are different each `POST` API.

Desired result, this works because I hardcoded the JSON.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if, I'm correct here:

I believe, what you are trying to do is, take the data from the HTML form and storing them, in form of an array and then pushing it into the json object. If so, then you'll always get a flat JSON structure. In order for you to get a dynamic nested JSON structure, you will have to design ng-model in your form as per your design.

```
formObject.name  
formObject.number  
formObject.url  
formObject.Children.ChildName  
formObject.Children.ChildNumber  
formObject.Children.Adresses.Line1  
formObject.Children.Adresses.Line2
```

If you can catch a drift, where I'm going with this.

Comment: well the textarea is being rendered using `ngFor*` see the edit